# Count all occurrences of a string in lots of files with grep

Tags: grep

I have a bunch of log files. I need to find out how many times a string occurs in all files.

```
grep -c string *
```

returns

```
...
file1:1
file2:0
file3:0
...
```

Using a pipe I was able to get only files that have one or more occurrences:

```
grep -c string * | grep -v :0

...
file4:5
file5:1
file6:2
...
```

How can I get only the combined count? (If it returns `file4:5, file5:1, file6:2`, I want to get back 8.)

Comment: Can you tell me what the grep -v :0 does ? . I know it counts for files having occurrences greater than 0. What does the -v option and :0 mean ?. Kindly let me know.

Comment: @GauthamHonnavara grep :0 looks for line that match the string :0. -v is an option to invert that search so instead using grep -v :0 means find all line that don't contain :0 so a line with file4:5 and file27:193 all would pass through since they don't contain :0

Comment: You can select multiple files using space. `grep file1 file2 --options`

Answer (score 305, accepted):

```
cat * | grep -c string
```

Comment: This has the same limitation that it counts multiple occurrences on one line only once. I am guessing that this behavior is OK in this case, though.

Comment: @Michael Haren Yes, there could be only one occurrence of string in a line.

Comment: I'd rather do `grep -c string<*` So just replacing the space with a less than.

Comment: Does not address multiple occurrences on a line

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to search in subdirectories too, whereas `grep -o` and `wc -l` does. cat is quicker in cases like the original question though.

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but it's what I came here hoping for & might help others: this won't work for `git grep` because it doesn't have `-o`, but `git grep <word> | grep -c <word>` does. Like the accepted answer, inaccurate for the case where there's multiple occurrences on one line. `git grep <word> | grep -o <word> | wc -l` will cover that case.

Comment: Note that the OP in the question also does not count multiple occurrences per line

Answer (score 333):

This works for multiple occurrences per line:

```
grep -o string * | wc -l
```

Comment: This also works: `grep -o string * --exclude-dir=some/dir/one/ --exclude-dir=some/dir/two | wc -l`.

Comment: `grep -ioR string * | wc -l` is what I use to do a case-insensitive, recursive, matching-only search

Comment: This one shows the relevant files and then the total count of matches: `grep -rc test . | awk -F: '$NF > 0 {x+=$NF; $NF=""; print} END{print "Total:",x}'`

Comment: Beware of limitations to grep: https://superuser.com/questions/1703029/is-there-a-limit-for-a-line-length-for-grep-command-to-process-correctly

Answer (score 29):

```
grep -oh string * | wc -w
```

will count multiple occurrences in a line

Comment: `grep -oh "... my that curry was strong" * >> wc` :)

Comment: @icc97 did you mean to pipe to wc or to cwc? (curse word count)

Answer (score 26):

Instead of using -c, just pipe it to wc -l.

```
grep string * | wc -l
```

This will list each occurrence on a single line and then count the number of lines.

This will miss instances where the string occurs 2+ times on one line, though.

Comment: Piping to "wc -l" works also nicely together with "grep -r 'test' ." which scans recursively all files for the string 'test' in all directories below the current one.

Answer (score 18):

```
cat * | grep -c string
```

One of the rare useful applications of `cat`.

Answer (score 14):

You can add `-R` to search recursively (and avoid to use cat) and `-I` to ignore binary files.

```
grep -RIc string .
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want number of occurrences per file (example for string "tcp"):

```
grep -RIci "tcp" . | awk -v FS=":" -v OFS="\t" '$2>0 { print $2, $1 }' | sort -hr
```

Example output:

```
53  ./HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp
21  ./WiFi/src/WiFiSTA.cpp
19  ./WiFi/src/ETH.cpp
13  ./WiFi/src/WiFiAP.cpp
4   ./WiFi/src/WiFiClient.cpp
4   ./HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.h
3   ./WiFi/src/WiFiGeneric.cpp
2   ./WiFi/examples/WiFiClientBasic/WiFiClientBasic.ino
2   ./WiFiClientSecure/src/ssl_client.cpp
1   ./WiFi/src/WiFiServer.cpp
```

Explanation:

- `grep -RIci NEEDLE .` - looks for string NEEDLE recursively from current directory (following symlinks), ignoring binaries, counting number of occurrences, ignoring case
- `awk ...` - this command ignores files with zero occurrences and formats lines
- `sort -hr` - sorts lines in reverse order by numbers in first column

Of course, it works with other grep commands with option `-c` (count) as well. For example:

```
grep -c "tcp" *.txt | awk -v FS=":" -v OFS="\t" '$2>0 { print $2, $1 }' | sort -hr
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Save days time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 12):

Obligatory AWK solution:

```
grep -c string * | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{x+=$2}END{print x}'
```

Take care if your file names include ":" though.

Answer (score 12):

Something different than all the previous answers:

```
perl -lne '$count++ for m/<pattern>/g;END{print $count}' *
```

Comment: nice to see an approach not using grep, esp as my grep (on windows) doesn't support the -o option.

Answer (score 7):

The AWK solution which also handles file names including colons:

```
grep -c string * | sed -r 's/^.*://' | awk 'BEGIN{}{x+=$1}END{print x}'
```

Keep in mind that this method still does *not* find multiple occurrences of `string` on the same line.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a simple `grep` to capture the number of occurrences effectively. I will use the `-i` option to make sure `STRING/StrING/string` get captured properly.

Command line that gives the files' name:

```
grep -oci string * | grep -v :0
```

Command line that removes the file names and prints 0 if there is a file without occurrences:

```
grep -ochi string *
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 5):

short **recursive** variant:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -c 'string'
```

Comment: Thank you! Only your solution worked for me (summed the matches of all the files).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a faster-than-grep AWK alternative way of doing this, which handles multiple matches of `<url>` per line, within a collection of XML files in a directory:

```
awk '/<url>/{m=gsub("<url>","");total+=m}END{print total}' some_directory/*.xml
```

This works well in cases where some XML files don't have line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Grep only solution which I tested with grep for windows:

```
grep -ro "pattern to find in files" "Directory to recursively search" | grep -c "pattern to find in files"
```

This solution will count all occurrences even if there are multiple on one line. `-r` recursively searches the directory, `-o` will "show only the part of a line matching PATTERN" -- this is what splits up multiple occurences on a single line and makes grep print each match on a new line; then pipe those newline-separated-results back into grep with `-c` to count the number of occurrences using the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Another oneliner using basic command line functions handling multiple occurences per line.

```
 cat * |sed s/string/\\\nstring\ /g |grep string |wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS='' -v FPAT='fast' '{print NF,FILENAME}' <file1..N>
```

Take a string, make it a line look for instance of fast and then print the number of fields with the filename.