# Grep Shell Scripting: How do I Count the Number of Occurrences of Each Substring?

Tags: shell, grep

Stack Overflow already has some great posts about counting occurrences of a string (eg. "foo"), like this one: [count all occurrences of string in lots of files with grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep).  However, I've been unable to find an answer to a slightly more involved variant.

Let's say I want to count how many instances of "`foo:[*whatever*]*whatever else*`" exist in a folder; I'd do:

```
grep -or 'foo:[(.*)]' * | wc -l
```

and I'd get back "55" (or whatever the count is).  But what if I have a file like:

```
foo:bar abcd
foo:baz efgh
not relevant line
foo:bar xyz
```

and I want to get count how many instances of `foo:bar` vs. how many of `foo:baz`s, etc.?  In other words, I'd like output that's *something* like:

```
bar 2
baz 1
```

I assume there's some way to chain `grep`s, or use a different command from `wc`, but I have no idea what it is ... any shell scripting experts out there have any suggestions?

P.S. I realize that if I knew the set of possible sub-strings (ie. if I knew there was only "foo:bar" and "foo:baz") this would be simpler, but unfortunately there set of "things that can come after `foo:`" is unknown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `sort` and `uniq -c`:

```
$ grep -orE 'foo:(.*)' * | sort | uniq -c
      2 foo:bar
      1 foo:baz
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you!  ... except I'm afraid I over-generalized in my original question.  There's also potentially (irrelevant) text after the grepped text, and that text would muck up the `uniq` I think?  I've tried to edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: @machineghost `-o` should give you only the actually matched text. Use a pattern other than `.*` if the matched portion is too much.

Comment: @machineghost Yes, try something like `\S+` (one or more non-whitespace characters) instead of `.*`.

Comment: Got it (in my actual case I had a closing paren as the boundary, so I wound up doing `foo\([^)]+\)`).