# How to get the count of fields in a delimited string?

Tags: bash, shell, cut

Given the following data:

```
 field1;field2;field3;field4;
```

How to get the number of fields in this string? 
For example, the command should give back **4** for this case.

Actually, I don't have the same number of contents in each line, but I need to return them all anyway. Once I manage to count the number of fields, I will also manage to make a loop to get them all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can say:

```
$ echo "field1;field2;field3;field4;" | grep -o ";" | wc -l
4
```

Alternatively,

```
$ tr -dc ';' <<< "field1;field2;field3;field4;" | wc -c
4
```

EDIT: In order to loop over the fields, you can say:

```
$ IFS=';' read -ra field <<< "field1;field2;field3;field4;"
$ for i in "${field[@]}"; do echo $i; done
field1
field2
field3
field4
```

Comment: It's working well. Just a short question. Am I doing it in the right way, if I want to get all fields, first recovering the number of fields, then with a loop FOR getting them all ? Or is there another functional command for that ?

Comment: @DoesJohnDo If you want to simply loop, you don't need to get the number of fields.  See edit above.

Comment: I see. However, I don't have the same nature of fields. I wrote field1, field2, etc. but it could have been Orange;Green;Bob;Table;. Do you have such convenient solution for that situation ?

Comment: Never mind, your answer suits me well. No need to more loose your time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note the last solution will give you an extra blank line at the end, because there's an `;`-separated blank field at the end of the line. You might want to drop trailing semicolons first.

Answer (score 19):

Using cut is not the recommended command to do the job as it can be done in one line using awk.

For e.g.

```
data='field1;field2;field3;field4;'
echo $data|awk -F';' '{print NF}'
```

Actually above will return 5 because in given data there is "semicolon" at the end, hence linux awk assumes that last field is empty.

But if this is expected to have it like this then you can use below command to subtract 1.

```
echo $data|awk -F';' '{print NF-1}'
```

Explanation:
-F option in awk is for delimiter, in this case it's semicolon (enclosed in single quote)
NF means Number of fields.

Answer (score 8):

Pure bash solution:

```
myStr='field1;field2;field3;field4;'
x="${myStr//[^;]}"                   # remove everything but the delimiter ';'
echo "${#x}"                         # get the length - outputs 4
```

Comment: This is elegant indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The option I have provided still holds up without bugs or manipulation.

```
j=0
i=1

while [ "$j" ]
do 
    j="$(cat dataFile.txt | cut -d[delimiter] -f$i)" 
    i="$(($i+1))"
done 

echo "$(($i-2))"
```

I initialize a variable `$j` to hold the results, and as long as the results exist, the loop counts each run. `cut` always runs till 2 past the field, explaining my `$(($i-2))` statement.

Put your data-file's delimiter after cut -d
I used a comma to separate my fields, so my actual code has:
cut -d, -f$i

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Your solution is not pure Bash at all: you're using the external programs `cat` and `cut`. And also, it's really ugly `:)`.

Comment: I'm excited that people actually read this!

Why is my code ugly? Should I write the multi-line version?

And I'm using BASH commands, rather than external programs like awk, a completely separate language set. Perhaps I have misinterpreted the difference between BASH, ZSH, Korn, and so forth, thinking that they each have their separate and often identical commands (rather than external programs) attached to their build.

Perhaps I misunderstand what a BASH command is, and a BASH command is an external program.

Wow, no spaces on comments.

Comment: In your terminal, type `help`. You'll have the list of all Bash builtins and keywords. When we say _pure Bash_ we mean only builtin commands! `cat` and `cut` are _not_ builtins. These are external commands.

Comment: Right on for the info. I tried using the awk option in an actual bash script and it failed to produce accurate results. The option I contributed remains consistent. While fooling with it, I've found it to be a function of my string manipulations, silly strings.

Comment: It's inefficient: you have to read the file N times to extract N fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
DATA="field1;field2;field3;field4;"
# save IFS
OLDIFS=$IFS
# set new IFS
IFS=";"
# set DATA as position parameters
set -- ${DATA//\*/\\*}
# simply get parameter count
echo "Fields: $#"
# restore IFS 
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: This is a common antipattern: it's subject to pathname expansion, and hence may not give the correct answer.

Comment: Can you provide an example of when this would fail?

Comment: `DATA='*;'`, run from a non empty directory…

Comment: Well, there are other glob characters: for example, `DATA='[hello];'` and if you happen to have files named `h`, `e`, `l` and `o`, then you'll get wrong results. In fact, people using this antipattern usually will use `set -f` to disable globbing. (At this point, I really feel that we're fighting against the shell instead of working with it).

Comment: In Bash, the canonical way to [split a string at a delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash/24426608#24426608) is to use `read`. So your code would be better written as: `IFS=';' read -r -d '' -a data_array < <(printf '%s\0' "$DATA"); echo "${#data_array[@]}"`.