# Gitbash version does not allow grep -o, is it possible to install new grep package?

Tags: linux, git, bash, cygwin

I am trying to do a directory-wide search for specific strings in JSON files.  The only problem is that these JSON files are only one line, so when I cat all of them, all strings occur a magical "1" time...since there's only one line even when I string them all together.

An easy solution, which I see a lot ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/grep-count-total-number-of-occurrences)), is `grep -o`.  Only problem is it doesn't come standard on my Gitbash.  I solved my immediate problem by just installing the latest Cygwin.  However, I'm wondering if there was an easier/more granular solution.  Is it possible to do the equivalent of "apt-get install" or similar on Gitbash?  Or can someone explain to me a quick-and-dirty way to extract and install the tar file in Gitbash?

Comment: I'm sure there's some good reason for grepping a JSON file, but do you know about [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq)?

Comment: Thanks @pak that will be really helpful going forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other approach is to:

- use a `cmd` session (using the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) which packaged with Git for Windows)
- use the `grep` included [Gnu for Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki), which supports the -o option (and actually allow you to use most of the *other* Unix commands that your script might be currently using)

Comment: Option #2 FTW!  Thanks a lot VonC!  Best part is I don't even need to open a Cygwin or bash window.  I can do it all from the same CMD window.  Awesome.

Option #1 didn't seem to work.  Maybe I just need the new Git for Windows.  I can't find it in my Program Files/Git folder, and when I copied the file or text into a file in said folder, I got the same error:

grep: invalid option -- o