# Counting occurrences of a specific number

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file consisting of one line with numbers such as 0 100 90 80 0 70 60

I'm trying to determine how many times the number 0 appears alone (in this case, twice).

I tried using this method which accounts for whitespace,

```
grep -o " 0 " file | wc -l
```

but it doesn't account for the first "0" since there's no whitespace preceding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count all occurrences of a string in lots of files with grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the *best* way, but you could use `xargs` with its `-n` flag in the following manner:

```
xargs -n1 < file  | grep ^0$ | wc -l
```

Comment: You can avoid the [useless use of `wc`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc); anything that looks like `grep x | wc -l` can be rewritten `grep -c x`.  As a further optimization, `grep -cFx 0` avoids regex entirely, and hence runs faster still.

Answer (score 3):

`grep -ow '0' num.txt | wc -l`

`-w` word match effectively does this to every pattern:

`grep -o '\b0\b' file | wc -l`

`\b` is a word boundary.

Interestingly `grep -cow` doesn't work to count the matches, which frustrates me.

Comment: The combination of `-co` would indeed be a nice feature for this, and doesn't have any obvious other useful interpretation.  There is a bug against GNU `grep` for this since many years: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?33080

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -Po '(^|\s)0($|\s)' file | wc -l
```

You just test if there's **a whitespace OR the beginning of line** before a zero.

Comment: `-P` is kind of overkill for this, you could articulate a very similar (but actually better!) regex with `grep -E`but of course, `grep -w` is completely standard.